# How to create buffer graphic layer in openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

Hello i am trying to create buffer for point in openlayers 3.I am able to display the with in buffer distance result.but not able to crea graphic layer. please help and what i tried i put it down.you can check it
 var style = new ol.style.Style({

```
    image: new ol.style.Circle({

        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            width: 5,
            color: 'blue'
        }),
        radius: 12
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '12px helvetica,sans-serif',


        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#fff',
            width: 2
        })
    })
});


for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
            ObjectIDs.push(myObject[i].asset_type);
            ObjectIDs.push(myObject[i].x);
            ObjectIDs.push(myObject[i].y);
        }
        var gridquerystr = ObjectIDs[0].toString();
        var x = ObjectIDs[1].toString();
        var y = ObjectIDs[2].toString();
        alert(gridquerystr);
        alert(x);
        alert(y);
        var pointgeom;
        var pointfeatures = [];
        //for (var i = 0 ; i < myObject.length ; i++) {

            pointgeom = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(x), parseFloat(y)], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"));

            pointfeature = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: pointgeom
            });
            pointfeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: bufferdistance,
                    width: 5
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: [51, 51, 51, .3]
                })
            }));
            pointfeatures.push(pointfeature);

            pointfeature.setStyle(style);

        var locations = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: pointfeatures,
            project: "EPSG:4326"

        });

        SearchResultsLayer.setSource(locations);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting buffer for the selected feature .But i want add own styles for the feature.Is there any other way.My working buffer function is

```
            var pointgeom;
            var pointfeatures = [];


            pointgeom = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(x), parseFloat(y)], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"));

            pointfeature = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: pointgeom
            });
            var poitnExtent = pointfeature.getGeometry().getExtent();
            var bufferedExtent = new ol.extent.buffer(poitnExtent, bufferdistance);

            var bufferPolygon = new ol.geom.Polygon(
            [
                [[bufferedExtent[0], bufferedExtent[1]],
                [bufferedExtent[0], bufferedExtent[3]],
                [bufferedExtent[2], bufferedExtent[3]],
                [bufferedExtent[2], bufferedExtent[1]],
                [bufferedExtent[0], bufferedExtent[1]]]
            ]
            );


            var bufferedFeature = new ol.Feature(bufferPolygon);

            vectorBuffers.getSource().addFeature(bufferedFeature);
```

Answer (score 0):

since you can retrieve the features that are within the buffer you created and only need to display it ( if I understood well what you wanted ), you only have to change the style of your point like this:

```
 Feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: yourBufferDistance,
      width: 2
      }),
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: [51, 51, 51, .3]
      })
    })
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have problem in creating a geom for the selected feature.can u help??

Comment: when i add styles to my function i am getting error like "Uncaught TypeError: pointgeom.setStyle is not a function".can u help what is error in it

Comment: Sorry my bad. The setStyle function is for the feature not for the geometry

Comment: Thank you i tried feature also.i am not able to get the results.

Comment: Do you get any error when using `feature.setStyle(...)`  ?

Comment: No Sir i am not getting any error.and i am able to add style for selected feature.the problem is not able to create buffer ti it.and i what i tried is i updated in question.

Comment: @indu what's in the variable style you're using here `pointfeature.setStyle(style);` ? this line is probably what's causing the problem, since the style is set on the style of pointfeature and you are changing it

Comment: style is for feature which i am selecting.i am adding one style for that location.style function i put in question.if i dont give style for the selected feature how to put buffer??and how to know from which point buffer we have to make

Comment: @indu a feature cannot get two styles at the same time, so it's either the buffer style or your defined style (the var style)

Comment: ok but when i remove var style also its not working.when i click for second time i am getting error "NS_ERROR_FAILURE: "

Comment: Hello i am getting i am getting buffer to full map.and if i pass bufferdistance 60meters i am getting buffer but i have one difficulty.how to fit buffer to extent.my buffer is changing the extent

Answer (score 0):

```
My working buffer for point is 

    var pointfeatures = [];
                var ObjectIDs = [];
                var obj = JSON.parse(data.d);
                for (var i = 0 ; i < obj.length ; i++) {
                    ObjectIDs.push(obj[i].x);
                    ObjectIDs.push(obj[i].y);
                    var x = ObjectIDs[0].toString();
                    var y = ObjectIDs[1].toString();

                    pointgeom = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(x), parseFloat(y)], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"));
                    pointfeature = new ol.Feature({
                        geometry: pointgeom
                    });




                    var extent = pointfeature.getGeometry().getExtent();
                    var bufferextent = new ol.extent.buffer(extent, bufferdistance);

                    var bufferPolygon = new ol.geom.Circle(extent, bufferdistance);

                    var bufferedFeature = new ol.Feature(bufferPolygon);
                    pointfeatures.push(bufferedFeature);

                    pointfeature.setStyle(style);


                    bufferedFeature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                            color: 'red',
                            width: 2
                        }),
                        image: new ol.style.Circle({
                            radius: bufferdistance,
                            width: 2
                        })


                    })
                    );

                    vectorBuffers.getSource().addFeature(bufferedFeature);
                }
                                locations = new ol.source.Vector({
                                    features: bufferextent,
                                    project: "EPSG:4326"
                                });

                                SearchResultsLayer.setSource(locations);

                    map.getView().fit(SearchResultsLayer.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());
```